# Construct sequence $u_j$ that converges to function $u$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$

Construct a sequence $(u_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$ and a function $u \in \mathcal{L}^1 (\lambda)$ such that $u_j \to u$ under the conditions that
$ \int_\mathbb{R} u  d\lambda = 5 $ and $\int_\mathbb{R} u_j  d\lambda = 3$ for all $j$.

I have found the sequence $u_j=5 \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}-2 \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[j,j+1]}$ and showed that the integral of this sequence $u_j$ equals 3.

To determine the function $u$ my plan is to find 
$$\lim_{j \to \infty} u_j(x) \to u$$
But if $j=\infty$ my interval $[j,j+1]=[\infty,\infty+1]$. I don't understand this part and don't know how to move on from here. Can someone pls elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \Bbb{R}$ then exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x<n, \forall n \geq N$

So $u_n(x)=51_{[0,1]},\forall n \geq N$ thus $u(x)-u_n(x)=0, \forall n \geq N$

So  $u_n(x) \to u(x)$ pointwise

Comment: How do we tell it converges pointwise?

Comment: I slightly edited my answer